# Как браузер загружает файл?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста, стало двруг любопытно, а как работают подобные сайты: ну знаете, типа, если добавить к названию youtube - приставку SS, то браузер начент скачивать файл.

Не могу понять, а как вдруг браузер начинает загружать файл с ютуба ?

Я имею ввиду, что видео с ютуба идет порциями, то сть браузер:

-Во первых, каким то образом все загружаемые части сохраняет в один файл.

-И во вторых, самое видео на ютуб представляет из себя два "потока": это собственно сам видео поток в формате .mp4 и отдельно аудиопоток в формате webm. То есть при скачке - браузер еще каким то образом - эти два формата объединяет в один файл что ли ?? Как он это делает ?

Comment: Это делает не браузер, а сервер с которого уже качается готовый mp4. ss не является какой-то магической приставкой или протоколом. Просто кто-то зарегистрировал домен ssyoutube.com, повесил скрипт который скачивает и отдаёт видео. Если же вопрос именно в том как с youtube получается mp4, то советую посмотреть https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl

Comment: @Ein, Спасибо! Я почему то всегда думал, что это именно браузер Пользователя делает.